# Javascript query on SharePoint list items returning same results

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to show the Title field of a SharePoint list using a JavaScript Query but it just keeps returning the same result regardless of the link I click on. So as below, if I click on 'Lenovo T470' that's what its hould show above the image but it keeps showing 'Lenovo X1 Carbon'.

[image: Service Catalogue Results]

If I change the code:

```
var DeviceName = result.Title;
```

to:

```
var DeviceName = item.Title;
```

it comes back undefined. Any ideas? Full code below:

```
function getDevices() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtTitleName = "";
//var txtDeviceType = "";


  var query  = "http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?select=ID,Title";





var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });


call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {

        var tempID = result.Id;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        var DeviceName = result.Title;

        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>";
        txtTitleName ="<p>" + DeviceName + "</p>";



    });
    $('#devices').append($(txtTitle));
    $('#devicetitle').append(txtTitleName);


});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
}
```

Comment: I don't see `item` variable anywhere in your JS code above. Probably it does not have a `Title` property. You can confirm it by inserting a `console.log(item)` right above `var DeviceName = item.Title` statement. In the log check if the item variable has the `Title` property or not.

Comment: could you provide us data.d.results ?